# Logic App Extracting String and Group them to Body Email

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Hello here is the snippet of my code and I am trying to get the AppId from this represented in the following manner in oder to send it via mail.

```
 {
                        "appId": "com.google.ios.youtube"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.keepassium.ios"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.markmcguill.strongbox"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.azureauthenticator"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.Office.Excel"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.Office.Powerpoint"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.Office.Word"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.onenote"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.rdc.ios"
                    },
                    {
                        "appId": "com.microsoft.skydrive"
                    }
```

What i expect is:
Youtube
ios
strongbox
......

I tried this

[image]

and I got this one

[image]

The Problem is: if I want to send a mail this will be sent at least 23 times and it'll cause chaos. How can I group them like this:

- Youtube
- ios
- strongbox

and send them once. Sorry to be long and thanks in advance for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

You can use **`Empty array variable`** and **`Join  Operator with space`**  for this:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

After this you can use Email as an action.

**`Code view:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@last(split(items('For_each')['appId'],'.'))",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Join": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@variables('var')",
                    "joinWith": " "
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Join"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "appId": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "appId"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Used **space - space** here:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's helpfull. Do you know if it is possible to represent the output like this? I mean in form of the list like an enumeration. 
-strongbox
- azureauthenticator
-Excel
- Powerpoint
-Word
-Word
-onenote
-ios-
- skydrive
- teams
-OnionBrowser
-Netflix

Comment: You can use - instead of space in join operator.

Comment: Also added the same in edit section of the answer